# Problems with a longlistselector in xaml windows phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am having problems with a longlist selector. Visual Studio said that the xaml is not valid but it compiles and works fine. The problem is that I need in the codebehind the text of the object "txtProjectName" and look like this object is not created.
this is the code:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=LocalizedResources.MainPagePanoramaItemGalleryTitle}">
            <!--Lista de líneas dobles con marcador de posición de imagen y ajuste de texto que usa un encabezado flotante que se desplaza con el contenido-->
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="GaleryLongListSelector" Margin="10" }">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,2,0,4" Height="100" Tap="StackPanel_Tap" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Grid.Column="0">
                                <!--Reemplazar el rectángulo por la imagen-->
                                <Border BorderThickness="1" Width="79" Height="79" BorderBrush="Red" Background="#FFFFC700"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txtProjectName" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="/Images/share.png" Width="80" Tap="Image_Tap" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

The datacontext is defined in the code behind because it is a database.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First - I'm not sure if this is a copy-pate mistake or you also have this in your code: `<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="GaleryLongListSelector" Margin="10" }">` - remove `}"`.

Your code should work, few remarks:

- your LLS should be filled with items which class should have a public property with suitable getter:

  ```
  public class Item
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- you should have a `List` or better `ObservableCollection` of your items:

  ```
  ObservableCollection<Item> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
  ```
- you should set this collection as ItemsSource:

  ```
  GaleryLongListSelector.ItemsSource = items;
  ```
- then you can add items and if its ObservableCollection then you will see your items automatically:

  ```
  items.Add(new Item { Name = "First" });
  ```

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Thankns for the answer. The "}" was a copy-paste mistake. Sorry. The rest of remarks that you did are ok in the code. I think that the code should work but it doesn't. Thanks

Comment: @LuisLópez Then the problem must be somewhere else. As I've [tried simple example works](http://1drv.ms/1kaWUEr). Check, maybe it will help.

Comment: I tried and this piece of code in a simple project don't return any exception or problem. The current project compìles and works fine but I need work with the txtProjectName texblock in the codebehind and I can't. The xaml code is underlined with a blue line and said invalid xaml but I don't find the error. Thanks for your help

Comment: @LuisLópez Is there a chance that you can share a simple code which reproduces the exception?